# csvreader and special characters in the csv header

Tags: csvsimple

I have a question quite similar to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269545/csvreader-and-respect-all-special-characters-in-the-csv-file). But I do have the underscore character in the heading which causes issure. One column has the name *q_u*. When I try:

```
\csvreader[
        respect all,
        head to column names
    ]{data.csv}{}
        {\\\hline\objId & \q_u}
```

It does not work because `\q_u` is not legal.

An example for data.csv:

```
objId,q_u
587722982832013381,-0.1237466
587724241230495806,0.04632737
```

What can I do about this without having to change the csv file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the second mandatory argument for setting aliases for the column names:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
objId,q_u
587722982832013381,-0.1237466
587724241230495806,0.04632737
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{$}r<{$} >{$}r<{$}}
\csvreader[
  respect all,
  head to column names,
]{\jobname.csv}{q_u=\qu}{\\\hline\objId & \qu }
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]